# How to add new samples to existing cascade training

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I trained Haar Classifier, using this tutorial:

http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

but results was not very good.
I don't want to retrain all classifier from the scratch with new samples, but better to made more acute existing classifier.

How can I train it, using new samples and already existed classifier files  (cascade and stages .xml)?

Comment: you can continue on old stages, but I'm not sure what happens if you replace the old .vec with a new one. Maybe you won't get enough positive samples anymore, because the pretrained classifier doesn't guarantee the minHitRate on those samples. Additional negatives might/should be less of a problem, but I guess you should prefer training new classifier from stage 0 to discriminate pos and neg better in early stages, hopefully leading to a better overall performance and better speed.

Comment: a bit more logical (if changing samples during training is possible at all): What do you want to achieve? You can never increase the generalized hit-rate by adding more/different positive samples (because lost samples are already lost in the pretrained stages), but you could in theory reduce the generalized false alarm rate by adding/replacing the negative samples during training.